# GetTextFromPage works in 5.5.0.0 but not in 5.5.6.0

Tags: itext

This is an odd one. I'm trying to extract text from a PDF which has inline images. If I use version 5.5.0.0 it works just fine. If I use the latest (version 5.5.6.0) it throws an exception. Why would an older version work fine and the new one not work? Bug?

Comment: Without any code or reference PDFs this question just really isn't answerable. Its possible that the PDF that you are using has invalid syntax that the earlier version didn't care about but the new version is more strict about. Its also possible that your code has a logic flaw that the newer version is exposing. And finally, it is possible that the newer version of iTextSharp has a bug. But without reproducible conditions there really isn't anything that we can do to help you.

Comment: I'd be happy to provide a sample document if it will help. Where do I send it?